# Replace text in the file with value followed by number

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I've tried to use [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html) module to replace port number in configuration file. Generally it can be done with:

```
replace: dest=config.file regexp='(.*)8080(.*)$' replace='\18081\2'
```

But it causes a problem because it tries to match backreference 18081.

I've tried replacing `\1` with `${1}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do it:

```
replace: dest=config.file regexp='(.*)8080(.*)$' replace='\g<1>8081\2'
```